# "Unpack requires a string argument of length 4" when unpacking floats?

Tags: python, hex, css-float

I am trying to convert hex value to float using (Python 2.7) the following method:

```
def hex2float(x):
    y = 0
    z = x.decode('hex') 
    try:
        y = struct.unpack('!f', z)[0]
    except:
        print sys.exc_info()[1]    
    print 'z = ' + z 
    print 'y = %s' % (y) 
    print 'x = ' + x
    return

def foo28():
    x = '615885'   #8.9398e-039
    hex2float(x)
```

The output is as follows:

```
unpack requires a string argument of length 4
z = aXà
y = 0
x = 615885
```

I notice that I get the exception message for really small values. Is there a proper way to convert hex values to floating values for such cases.

Comment: Yes, because you need 4 bytes to get the 32 bits (for a 32-bit float) that *represent* the float. There is no trivial way to "pad" this number in IEEE-754 that I am aware of; perhaps the source is corrupted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need four bytes to unpack, so prepend null bytes if necessary:

```
z = x.decode('hex') 
z = '\0' * (4 - len(z)) + z
```

Normally `str.decode` only outputs as much bytes as necessary to represent the value, so that's why you only see it happen for small values.

This works perfectly:

```
>>> z = '615885'.decode("hex")
>>> z = '\0' * (4 - len(z)) + z
>>> struct.unpack('!f', z)
(8.939797951825212e-39,)
```

If you're going to do doubles as well this solution still works, just change `4` to `8`.